# Ubuntu changes file dates on mount

Tags: mount, 20.04, exfat

I just plugged the SD card from my GoPro camera into my Ubuntu laptop, it got mounted, and when I looked into it with the file manager I noticed that all modification timestamps were wrong. Specifically, pretty exactly 1 month into the future. To verify this I unmounted the card, took the GoPro, recorded a short video, took some images, plugged it into a windows computer and verified that the date and time of the camera was correct. It was. September 21st, 16:52. Then I unmounted the card, plugged it into the Ubuntu laptop again, and voila: the same file now has a modification and creation date of October 21st.

Why does Ubuntu change the modification date upon mount and how can I stop this?

The `mount` entry at that point:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /media/gerald/C8AC-6CE5 type exfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Update: I just checked the images I imported last from my other camera, which uses a FAT32 formatted card. Seems like the problem only affects cards formatted with exfat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling with this as well. Apparently this is a known bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1872504

First reply says *Installing exfat-fuse and exfat-utils results in the correct behaviour* This only half worked in my case. I had to specify the timezone when the SD card mounts. I did this by editing the fstab file (adding option tz=UTC), so it always mounts with the appropriate time.

Comment: I don't think *Installing exfat-fuse and exfat-utils results in the correct behaviour* is true. Some time ago I've had issue with timestamps and it fixed the issue for me, but now I got issues again (I didn't use my pc for a while so not sure what exactly changes) and I got rid of the issues by uninstalling those utils. OK, finally I've ended up with inconsistent state again (as seen by windows and linux) and gave up on using exfat.